# Convert and compare string format date with dd/mm format date?

Tags: javascript, angular

I am receiving "14 Mar" date format in JSON response. I need to convert "14 Mar" date format in to "03/14" date format and than compare with today date.

Comment: Hi, only '14 Mar'? No year?

Comment: please provide code what you have done so far

Comment: @wentjun yes no year. Actually want to compare "14 Mar" with current day date "03/14".

Comment: @TheParam it's my 1st day so it's going above me. Any help will be helpful to me.

Comment: @John, ok, and what exactly you want to compare? If they are similar? Or larger?

Comment: @wentjun similar

Comment: Ok, I have updated my answer

Comment: Sorry, I have made another slight change

Comment: @wentjun i am receiving "14 Mar" date in variable(check). so how would i place check variable in your date1 variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you convert them to JavaScript [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) objects. From there, you can do all sorts of comparison. I have stated an example below.

```
const currentYear = new Date().getFullYear();
// check = '14 Mar'
const date1 = new Date(`${check} ${currentYear}`).setHours(0,0,0,0);

const date2 = new Date().setHours(0,0,0,0);

console.log(date1 === date2);
```

However, I am assuming that your input date values are year-agnostic, thus I converted to your input date such that it belongs to the same year as today's date.

In addition, I set both dates to contain the 'same' time (hours, mins, etc) such that we are only comparing the date and month.

Comment: i am receiving "14 Mar" date in variable(check). so how would i place check variable in your date1 variable?

Comment: What is the name of your variable?

Comment: Shall I assume your variable is in this format: const receivedDate = '14 Mar'?

Comment: it's coming in "check"

Comment: Ok, I have updated it. Just pass 'check' into the template literals expression, like how I did it?

Comment: Anyway, just a short tip, it will be more suitable to tag your question as 'JavaScript', instead of just 'json' or 'angular', since your question is not framework specific

Answer (score 1):

Convert your receiving date in to JS data using this,

```
let date = Date.parse(your_receiving_date);
```

Now compare it with today.

Comment: I did this. But why it is not going in same date case? Please take a look at it.
let check = Date.parse(this.check_date);
       console.log("check:",check);  
       var today_date = Date.now();
       console.log("today_date:",today_date);  
       if (check == today_date) {  
            console.log("date is same ");  
        }else {  
            console.log("date is not same ");  
        }

Comment: @John please do not post any code in comments. It is difficult to read. If you have tried some code, post it in the question or create a  minimal reproduction using stackblitz

Comment: @John : what @SachinGupta said, but also not that the code you pasted in the comments does not call `setHours(0,0,0,0)` for check_date nor today_date, so they're never going to be the same

Comment: @John, this has two reasons. 1. when you parse, the year is not parsed. So wrong year. 2. Date.now() has the current time in it. Comparison is done in milliseconds, So result is wrong

Comment: @DulanjayaTennekoon yeah i got it. Working on other solution.